# Exception while submit spark job on yarn cluster with remote jvm

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-sql

I am using below java code to submit job on yarn-cluster.

```
public ApplicationId submitQuery(String requestId, String query,String fileLocations) {
    String driverJar = getDriverJar();
    String driverClass =  propertyService.getAppPropertyValue(TypeString.QUERY_DRIVER_CLASS);
    String driverAppName = propertyService.getAppPropertyValue(TypeString.DRIVER_APP_NAME);
    String extraJarsNeeded = propertyService.getAppPropertyValue(TypeString.DRIVER_EXTRA_JARS_NEEDED);

      String[] args = new String[] {
               // the name of your application
               "--name",
               driverAppName,

               // memory for driver (optional)
               "--driver-memory",
               "1000M",

               // path to your application's JAR file 
               // required in yarn-cluster mode      
               "--jar",
               "local:/home/ankit/Repository/Personalization/rtis/Cust360QueryDriver/target/SnapdealCustomer360QueryDriver-jar-with-selective-dependencies.jar",

               "--addJars",
               "local:/home/ankit/Downloads/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar,local:/home/ankit/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar,local:/home/ankit/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar",


               // name of your application's main class (required)
               "--class",
               driverClass,

               "--arg",
               requestId,

               "--arg",
               query,

               "--arg",
               fileLocations,

               "--arg",
               "yarn-client"
           };

      System.setProperty("HADOOP_CONF_DIR", "/home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.0/etc/hadoop");
      Configuration config = new Configuration();
      config.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", propertyService.getAppPropertyValue(TypeString.RESOURCE_MANGER_URL));
      config.set("fs.default.name", propertyService.getAppPropertyValue(TypeString.FS_DEFAULT_NAME));

      System.setProperty("SPARK_YARN_MODE", "true");



      SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();

      ClientArguments cArgs = new ClientArguments(args, sparkConf); 

      // create an instance of yarn Client client
       Client client = new Client(cArgs, config, sparkConf);

       ApplicationId id = client.submitApplication();

       return id;

}
```

Job is getting submitted to yarn-cluster and i am able to retrieve application id but i am getting below Exception while running job on spark cluster.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 13 more
```

though mentioned class in /home/ankit/Downloads/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar. looks like  jar mentioned in --addJars is not getting added in driver's spark context.

Am i doing something wrong?? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying on Cloudera's distribution ? spark.yarn.jar in the CDH 5.4 config has a 'local:' prefix for local files, but Spark version >= 1.5 does not like this, you should just use the full path name for your spark assembly. See also [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/About-spark-1-5-release/td-p/31673/page/3).

Answer (score 0):

Try building JAR without spark dependency and pass dependent jars with --jars in spark submit. Most of the times ClassNotFoundException is due to spark and application itself is dependent on same jar. 
Suggested solution:

1. package without dependency and add dependent jars with --jars during
   spark-submit
2. Modify application to use same version of third-party
   library as spark has
3. Use shading in your build tool